# Computing data on the fly vs. pre-computed table

Tags: c++, c, optimization

A common technique to save some time is to use a table of pre-computed values, instead of computing the value every time on the fly. For example, for an integer approximation of the logarithm.

Could it happen that fetching a value for the first time will actually be slower than computing it because the table is far away in memory (the DATA segment) and the access causes a page load? Is there a way to force the compiler to put the data closer to the code?

I presume the table has to be static, does it then matter if it is declared locally inside the given function or globally?

Comment: AFAIK the instruction pipeline and the data paging are unrelated. And defining a static array locally only affects its visibility.

Comment: In C++ you can even make tables at compile time using constexpr which could be more efficient. Maybe you could force a prefetch at the start of your program? 
Anyway is this a theoretical bottleneck or are you experience (measured) performance issues?

Comment: A pre-computed table saves time if the cost of computing the function is greater than the time required to read from the table — even when the table has not previously been read from.  If the computation cost (time) is smaller than might be needed to read the data from (spinning magnetic) disk, then maybe it shouldn't be precomputed.  There's a fairly large range of overlap where you have to use judgement.  These days, if the computation doesn't need much memory access, the pre-computed table quite possibly isn't a benefit.  I trust you can detect the "it depends" running through this comment.

Comment: Generally, you should avoid tagging a question with both C and C++.  In this case, you probably get away with it because you're not asking for code — indeed, the question could apply equally to languages other than just C and C++.

Comment: FYI, distance has very little to do with computers.  Generally, anything within the processor's address space can be accessed at the same quick speed.

Comment: Depends on how the value is calculated.  Interpolation and table lookups can be faster than calculating a Taylor Series.

Comment: The main problem is the size of the table - larger tables mean a higher chance of cache misses or worse (disk IO). For fast computation that would require a huge table (e.g. adding a pair of 32-bit integers) it can be extremely bad, and for extremely expensive computation that could be replaced by a tiny table it can be extremely good. Also note that there's a middle-ground, like "`if (not previously calculated) { calculate it and store it in dynamically allocated a table } else { use the table }`" - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: Modern processor have separate instruction and data caches. Having data in a different location is not really a problem. In fact putting data in the code using tricks can help to reduce data cache misses but it can also cause more instruction cache misses somewhere else because of a bigger code (and this is not easy to track). If accesses to the table are not uniform, you can use multiple tables (a small one and a big one). If the accesses are done in a loop, then you can prefetch the table. If the table is big and used with a cold cache, then there is not much to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it happen that fetching a value for the first time will actually be slower than computing it because the table is far away in memory (the DATA segment) and the access causes a page load?

Yes, it can happen. Whether a page load occurs is not the only consideration. This question is hugely dependent on system architecture and the tools used. It can be affected by whether instruction cache and data cache are separate (and on which levels of cache), the cache geometry, other patterns of use in the program, processor speed, cache speed, memory speed, and more.

Sometimes high-performance software will “touch” data it does not need now but anticipates using in the future to cause it to be loaded into memory and/or cache so that it is available more quickly in the future when it is needed. (Depending on system architecture and circumstances, loading data from memory may not slow down any subsequent instructions if no such instruction uses the loaded data, or there may be instructions that explicitly request data be loaded into cache but not a CPU register.)

> Is there a way to force the compiler to put the data closer to the code?

When it is necessary to closely control where code and data are located in memory, it is usually done with features of the linker and/or program loader, and possibly with assembly language, not with the compiler. The involvement of the compiler may be to compile small functions into separate object modules or with features allowing functions to be separated from other functions, so that the linker can rearrange the functions and data according to other instructions it is given.

> I presume the table has to be static,…

No, “static” in the sense of object lifetime is largely irrelevant to system performance except in systems where some data may be put into ROM or different types of memory with different performance characteristics. As for how the keyword `static` affects identifier scope, that is irrelevant to memory performance.

> … does it then matter if it is declared locally inside the given function or globally?

Not unless the compilers has features for controlling the location of one of these and not the other.